# Ошибка OSError: Failed to read 55, 755 because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format

Tags: python, config

вот код

```py
import pyautogui as pag
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

def chrome_mail():
    pag.moveTo(config["Browser"]["chrome"])
    pag.click()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    chrome_mail()
```

вот файл конфигурации

```
[Browser]
chrome= 55, 755
huiman= 702, 469
;huiman = 544, 469
```

вот полная ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\romaz\Desktop\teests\mailanddsreg\AccountCreator.py", line 119, in <module>
    chrome_mail()
  File "C:\Users\romaz\Desktop\teests\mailanddsreg\AccountCreator.py", line 16, in chrome_mail
    pag.moveTo(config["Browser"]["chrome"])
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 598, in wrapper
    returnVal = wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 1280, in moveTo
    x, y = _normalizeXYArgs(x, y)
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 661, in _normalizeXYArgs
    location = locateOnScreen(firstArg)
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 175, in wrapper
    return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 213, in locateOnScreen
    return pyscreeze.locateOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 372, in locateOnScreen
    retVal = locate(image, screenshotIm, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 352, in locate
    points = tuple(locateAll(needleImage, haystackImage, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 206, in _locateAll_opencv
    needleImage = _load_cv2(needleImage, grayscale)
  File "C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 169, in _load_cv2
    raise IOError("Failed to read %s because file is missing, "
OSError: Failed to read 55, 755 because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format
```

Comment: Функция moveTo принимает два числа, а вы вместо чисел передаёте в неё одну строку `"55, 755"`, в итоге получается что попало

Comment: @andreymal а как исправить?